# tkinter protocol WM_DELETE_WINDOW not working on extra windows

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to run some extra windows in my tkinter app (tkinter 8.6, python 3.5, ubuntu xenial). while I can pick up the delete window protocol OK from the main app, it never gets called on additional windows.I want to let the user close the window with the 'X', but I do need to know when they do this.

I expect the answer will be depressingly obvious once I see it!

This simple test app demonstrates.....

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import tkinter

class app(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.child1 = None
        self.geometry('600x400')
        w = tkinter.Button(self, command=self.bclick, text='button1')
        w.pack()
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.appClose)

    def bclick(self):
        if self.child1 == None:
            self.child1 = tkinter.Toplevel()
        else:
            self.child1.destroy()
            self.child1 = None

    def appClose(self):
        print('main app close')
        self.destroy()

class wind1(tkinter.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('window 1')
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.window1Close)
        self.geometry('600x400')

    def window1Close(self):
        print("window1Close")
        self.destroy()

if __name__=="__main__":
    print(tkinter.TkVersion)
    app().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right: it's going to be depressingly obvious when you see it. Sorry for the bad news.

When you click on the button, you create an instance of `tkinter.Toplevel`, you do *not* create an instance of `wind1`. Since you are getting a generic `Toplevel`, it does not have the binding to `WM_DELETE_WINDOW`.